# Vue @click event is not working in my version of Edge

Tags: vue.js, microsoft-edge

Vue @click event is not working in my version of Edge.

I tried following:

```
<button @click="test()">Test</button>
<SomeComponentWithClickEventThatWorksInOtherBrowsers @click="test()">
// same with @click.native="test()"
// same without ()

...

test(): void {
  console.log('test');
  // other stuff that works in Chrome & Safari & Opera      
}
```

console.log() also not working in Edge as well as some data bindings. However, I am not getting any console, terminal or lint errors.
 My Edge version:

```
Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0
Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18362
2019
```

Did you ever had same problems? What cound be reason? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please provide source code for SomeComponentWithClickEventThatWorksInOtherBrowsers.

Answer (score 0):

Why `void`?

The most common way:

```
   test: function() {
      console.log('test');
   }
```

And you call it with `@click="test"`

and i hope you putted everything inside `methods`

```
    methods:{
       test: function() {
          console.log('test');
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to [this guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) about listening to click events in vue.js. I made a sample to show how to make `console.log()` work in vue.js, you could refer to it. You could also test it in Edge and it works well in my Edge 44.18362.1.0:

```js
var example = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  methods: {
    test: function() {
      console.log('test');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  <button @click="test">test</button>
</div>
```